# PHP efficiently accessing values in a JSON array on different levels

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

Working on a personal project that will pull results from an API with full details of each pokemon.

So far I got the contents of the URL and returned the results into a JSON array format.

At the moment I am stuck on trying to retrieve results for[stats] inside from the array in an efficient manner.

```
private function getGenOnePokemon()
{
    // the url of the api 
    $url = $this->baseUrl;

    //get the contents of $url var and decode it into a json array
    $json = file_get_contents($url , true);
    $pokemon = json_decode($json, true, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    // array output of pokemon
    echo '<pre> ';
    print_r($pokemon);
    echo'</pre>';


    //echo out value  as speed

    foreach($pokemon['results'][0] as $happy)
    {
        echo $happy['name'] . '<br />';
    }


    // echo base_stat value for speed with value of 90
    echo $pokemon['stats'][0]['base_stat'];


}
```

However I do not seem to get anywhere much printing values/keys as I need to add something else to have full access to the values?

Would prefer not to directly access results, like I am doing with `base_stat` as plan on using this logic to pass into HTML View layer later.

Example of print_r dump (not full dump as really long) Full example: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu

```
Array
(
[forms] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [url] => https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/25/
                [name] => pikachu
            )

    )

[abilities] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [slot] => 3
                [is_hidden] => 1
                [ability] => Array
                    (
                        [url] => https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/31/
                        [name] => lightning-rod
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [slot] => 1
                [is_hidden] => 
                [ability] => Array
                    (
                        [url] => https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/9/
                        [name] => static
                    )

            )

    )

[stats] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [stat] => Array
                    (
                        [url] => https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/6/
                        [name] => speed
                    )

                [effort] => 2
                [base_stat] => 90
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [stat] => Array
                    (
                        [url] => https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/5/
                        [name] => special-defense
                    )

                [effort] => 0
                [base_stat] => 50
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [stat] => Array
                    (
                        [url] => https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/4/
                        [name] => special-attack
                    )

                [effort] => 0
                [base_stat] => 50
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [stat] => Array
                    (
                        [url] => https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/3/
                        [name] => defense
                    )

                [effort] => 0
                [base_stat] => 40
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [stat] => Array
                    (
                        [url] => https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/2/
                        [name] => attack
                    )

                [effort] => 0
                [base_stat] => 55
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [stat] => Array
                    (
                        [url] => https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/1/
                        [name] => hp
                    )

                [effort] => 0
                [base_stat] => 35
            )

    )
```

Any advice on how to access the data using `foreach` or other tips greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$pokemon` array doesn't contain a `results` field. There's only an `forms` field. So you should iterate over `forms` to print the names of the forms.

```
foreach($pokemon['forms'] as $happy) {
    echo $happy['name'] . '<br />';
}
```

You could do the same thing with the stats

```
foreach($pokemon['stats'] as $stat) {
    $base_stat = $stat['base_stat'];
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a specific function designed to target columnar data from arrays.  It is called `array_column()`

If you want to isolate all of the `name` elements inside the `forms` subarray, use this:

```
$names=array_column($pokemon['forms'],'name');
```

If you want to isolate all of the `base_stat` elements inside of the `stats` subarray, use this:

```
$base_stats=array_column($pokemon['stats'],'base_stat');
```

Now you will have `$names` and `$base_stats` which are single-dimensional arrays by which you can perform additional processes or return from the function.  Clean, intuitive, and simple.